# How to make input information disappear after user interacts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I'm writing code which requires different types of user input and I want the user to see what to write where but I want the information I'm giving to disappear as soon as the user starts typing for example:

```
question = "insert number here"
xa = float(input(f"xa ={question} "))
```

How do I make the question variable disappear when the user starts typing a number?

Comment: What platform are you writing for? For example, if you're using tkinter, try this: [How to insert a temporary text in a tkinter Entry widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30491721/4518341)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: What is your basic code, which doesn't show the input information yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm came cross with this solution

> pip install pynput

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

question = "insert number here"

def on_press(key):
    print ("\033[A                             \033[A")

    xa = float(input())
    print (f"xa = {xa}")
    return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    print(f"xa ={question} ")
    listener.join()
```

it's going to clear last one line in python output (.e.g your question) when user start typing

Comment: hi i did what you said and it shows me: unresolved import 'pynput.keyboard'

Comment: this is another issue, i guess you are using vscode,
if you are, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code) hope it's fix your issue