# How to add a placeholder in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, onclick

How would I add a placeholder to an entry in `tkinter`? I don't believe it has a placeholder function like HTML for example. I figured out that to make the text disappear when you click it, you will have to add an `onclick` event, but how do I create the `onclick` event and how do you make the text appear in the first place? Here is the code I'm working with.

I would like it to say " Enter your integer here"

## Textbox

```
    vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate), '%S')
    self.text = Entry(self, validate='key', vcmd=vcmd)
    self.text.pack()
       
def onValidate(self, S):
    if S in '0123456789.':
        return True
    return False

def clear_entry(self):
    self.text.delete(0, END)
    self.text.pack()
```

Comment: Have you done research?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add placeholder to an Entry in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820178/how-to-add-placeholder-to-an-entry-in-tkinter)

Comment: i saw that before and the code wasnt working when i put it in, so i thought i could get more of a tailored explanation on how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U can't add placeholder like HTML as far as i know, but u can make similar behavior.  When you make entry you can do something like>

```
from tkinter import *   

def clear_entry(event, entry):
    entry.delete(0, END)

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)

entry.pack()
placeholder_text = 'some text'
entry.insert(0, placeholder_text)

entry.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: clear_entry(event, entry))

root.mainloop()
```

P.S: I've wrote this from my head , haven't tested it

Comment: ive had a huge issue with entry fields in tkinter, when i ran your code it just displayed a blank white app with no widgets

Comment: I have tested it, and it works, you just have top put the code in function , or put clear_entry function  above line root = Tk()

Comment: maybe its because im on Mac but it is still not working

Comment: it doesn't matter, it should work on any system, i have edited code try again

Comment: bingo! the issue was entry(parent) instead of entry(root)

Comment: yes, that's because i wrote that from my head first, i haven't tested it, i changed it later