# How to have placeholder in Tkinter Entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a software login page in Python 3.8 with Tkinter.
How can I add placeholder in Tkinter Entry like the one in this image?

[image]

**With this code:**
`E1 = Text(M, bd=0, height=35, width=1000, font=("Calibri 20"), bg="ghost white")`
`E1.pack(side=LEFT)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928390/6849682

Comment: https://github.com/dorukwagle/tkinter-input-box
use this package.

Answer (score 3):

this should work:

```
from tkinter import *


def focus_out_entry_box(widget, widget_text):
    if widget['fg'] == 'Black' and len(widget.get()) == 0:
        widget.delete(0, END)
        widget['fg'] = 'Grey'
        widget.insert(0, widget_text)


def focus_in_entry_box(widget):
    if widget['fg'] == 'Grey':
        widget['fg'] = 'Black'
        widget.delete(0, END)


entry_text = 'First name'
my_entry = Entry(font='Arial 18', fg='Grey')
my_entry.insert(0, entry_text)
my_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda args: focus_in_entry_box(my_entry))
my_entry.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda args: focus_out_entry_box(my_entry, entry_text))
my_entry.pack()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set default value for the entry:

```
ui = Tk()

e= Entry(ui)
e.insert(0, 'text')
e.pack()
```

Comment: Hey, I am getting this error: _tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0"

Comment: try with "end" instead of 0 or try to leave it out