# Placeholder in Tkinter Entry ? possible

Tags: python, tkinter, placeholder

Is Placeholder in a tkinter entry field is possible.
I saw it is possible using Objects or classes. But don't know actually how to do that

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820178/how-to-add-placeholder-to-an-entry-in-tkinter

Answer (score 2):

Use `.insert()` to add default value place holder

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

e = Entry(win)
e.insert(0, 'Placeholder')
e.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `StringVar`.

```
variable = tkinter.StringVar(root, “Spam”)
entry = tkinter.Entry(root, textvariable=variable)
#Set it to something else:
variable.set(“Bacon”)
```