# How to make tkinter entry switch between showing the text and showing a "*"

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make the entry widget show the place
holder text [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfRRJ.png)
But then when you click it it shows nothing in it like it should,
but if you click off of it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfiNy.png),
If anyone knows please let me know.
Info on what I'm doing:
This is my first GUI project I'm doing 'on my own' by that i mean no YouTube tutorial. I'm trying to make a password manager
This is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import os



class PlaceholderEntry(Entry):
    #original code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820178/how-to-add-placeholder-to-an-entry-in-tkinter
    #credit to Nae on stack overflow
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="", placefg='grey', bg='white', fg='black', insertbackground="black", show=None):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.placefg = placefg
        self.fg = fg
        self.show = show
        self.none = None
        self['bg'] = bg
        self['insertbackground'] = insertbackground
    

        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.focus_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.focus_out)

        self.insert_placeholder()

    def insert_placeholder(self):
        self.delete(0,'end')
        self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
        self['fg'] = self.placefg


    def focus_in(self, *args):
        if self['fg'] == self.placefg:
            self.delete('0', 'end')
            self['fg'] = self.fg
            self['show'] = self.show

    def focus_out(self, *args):
        if not self.get():
            self.insert_placeholder()
        self['show'] = self.none
    

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')#clears terminal

root = Tk() 
root.title("entry")
root.geometry("400x400")#sets window size
root.configure(bg='#222222')#for grey background use #222222

c = ("#ffffff", "#222222", "#111111","#555555","#000000")#colors

username = Entry(root, show="*")

password = PlaceholderEntry(root, show="*", placeholder="password", placefg=c[3], bg=c[2],fg=c[0], insertbackground=c[0])
username.pack()
password.pack()  
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have a button that links to a function that checks the current state and changes the mode using, `config`

Comment: thank you this works and i did find out what i was doing wrong when ever is says "None" i just have to say "" instead