# What is causing this strange focus behavior with my PlaceholderEntry class?

Tags: python, tkinter, placeholder

I've put together a simple class that inherits from `ttk.Entry` in order to toggle some placeholder text on focus events (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928390/8512262)).

The odd thing is that my placeholder text is only cleared on `'<FocusIn>'` *if* I include `print(self['foreground'])` in my `set_placeholder()` method, otherwise the placeholder text isn't cleared when the Entry is focused.

I've included an example app with two `PlaceholderEntry` widgets to demonstrate the focus behavior.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    """Example app"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ph_entry_a = PlaceholderEntry(self, 'Hello')
        self.ph_entry_a.pack()
        self.ph_entry_b = PlaceholderEntry(self, 'there')
        self.ph_entry_b.pack()


class PlaceholderEntry(ttk.Entry):
    """Entry widget with focus-toggled placeholder text"""
    def __init__(
        self, parent, placeholder='', color='#828790', *args, **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self._ph_color = color
        self._default_fg = self.cget('foreground')  # default foreground color
        # focus bindings
        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.set_placeholder)
        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.clear_placeholder)
        # initialize placeholder
        self.set_placeholder()

    def set_placeholder(self, *args):  # on focus out
        if not self.get():  # if the entry has no text...
            self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
            self.configure(foreground=self._ph_color)
            # clearing the placeholder doesn't work without this line:
            print(self['foreground'])
            # I've also tried this, and it works as well...
            # str(self.cget('foreground'))

    def clear_placeholder(self, *args):
        if self.cget('foreground') == self._ph_color:
            self.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.configure(foreground=self._default_fg)
            # it makes no difference if I have a 'print' or 'str' statement here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Root()
    app.mainloop()
```

I'm wondering if this has something to do with garbage collection, but I'm honestly not sure. For what it's worth, assigning the `foreground` to a variable in the `set_placeholder` method e.g. `fg = self['foreground']` makes no difference. Can anybody tell me what's going on here? Any info is much appreciated.

*FWIW: I'm using Python 3.11 64-bit on Windows 10*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `cget` returns a `<class '_tkinter.Tcl_Obj'>` and not a string that is whats causing your evaluation to fail. You could solve it in different ways.

1. `self.cget('foreground').string`
2. `str(self.cget('foreground'))`

A slightly longer answer, but I'm not aware of all the details, is that in `tcl` everything is written in strings text and in order to be useful in python in needs to be `translated`. Therefore such methods on your root window, to be exact on the instance of `_tkinter.tkapp` exists as `getint` and so on.

The implementation of tkinter in python is really good and I can't imagine the countless hours it took to make it work. But some features however are not perfect. Take the return value from `configure` for example. Normally you would expect a dictionary of key and value pairs but they are not translated well and you get synonyms for the keyword in tcl as well. It's a complex topic that I wouldn't claim I'm an expert it.

As @Bryan Oakley pointed out in the comments:

> I think this is just a bug in ttk. The cget returns this tclObj for
> the color options of a ttk widget, but it returns a proper string with
> tkinter widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley occasionally it happens. I did not find the actual cause, but to be honest the tkinter `__init__` file is pretty messy. I also noted recently that there exists various redundant methods and some are slightly different from each other. I think a problem of the implementation is that different people have developed different aspects. Some methods are unnecessary, but might became it later and no one noticed it.

Comment: I think this is just a bug in ttk. The cget returns this Tcl_Obj for the color options of a ttk widget, but it returns a proper string with tkinter widgets.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report [#98815](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/98815)